# sendToTarget on the client side not calling fromapp method on the executor side in quckfix

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

On client side the log information is like :

```
>>>>Creating the following order: 
    push order 15:47:21
    Message: 8=FIX.4.29=2554=158=Cancel My Order!10=233
    SessionID:FIX.4.2:Xtech->HENGSHENG
    Sending...
>>>>15:47:21:Into toAdmin
    SessionID: 8=FIX.4.29=7135=A34=23849=Xtech52=20210102-07:47:21.00056=HENGSHENG98=0108=3010=232
FIX.4.2:Xtech->HENGSHENG
>>>>15:47:21:Into toApp
    SessionID: 8=FIX.4.29=7934=23949=Xtech52=20210102-07:47:21.00056=HENGSHENG54=158=Cancel My Order!10=221
    Recieved the following message: FIX.4.2:Xtech->HENGSHENG
>>>>15:47:27:Into toAdmin
    SessionID: 8=FIX.4.29=10935=534=24049=Xtech52=20210102-07:47:27.00056=HENGSHENG58=MsgSeqNum too low, expecting 14 but received 110=190
FIX.4.2:Xtech->HENGSHENG
>>>>15:47:27:Into Logout
    SessionID: FIX.4.2:Xtech->HENGSHENG
>>>>15:47:27:Into toAdmin
    SessionID: 8=FIX.4.29=7135=A34=24149=Xtech52=20210102-07:47:27.00056=HENGSHENG98=0108=3010=232
FIX.4.2:Xtech->HENGSHENG
>>>>15:47:27:Into Logout
    SessionID: FIX.4.2:Xtech->HENGSHENG
```

On executor side:

```
- 15:47:21 - Into fromAdmin
    Message: 8=FIX.4.29=7135=A34=23849=Xtech52=20210102-07:47:21.00056=HENGSHENG98=0108=3010=232
    Session: FIX.4.2:HENGSHENG->Xtech
- 15:47:24 - Into toAdmin
    Message: 8=FIX.4.29=6935=A34=149=HENGSHENG52=20210102-07:47:24.00056=Xtech98=0108=3010=134
    Session: FIX.4.2:HENGSHENG->Xtech
- 15:47:27 - Into toAdmin
    Message: 8=FIX.4.29=6635=234=249=HENGSHENG52=20210102-07:47:27.00056=Xtech7=116=010=218
    Session: FIX.4.2:HENGSHENG->Xtech
- 15:47:30 - Into onLogon
    Session: FIX.4.2:HENGSHENG->Xtech
- 15:47:30 - Into fromAdmin
    Message: 8=FIX.4.29=10935=534=24049=Xtech52=20210102-07:47:27.00056=HENGSHENG58=MsgSeqNum too low, expecting 14 but received 110=190
    Session: FIX.4.2:HENGSHENG->Xtech
- 15:47:33 - Into toAdmin
    Message: 8=FIX.4.29=5735=534=349=HENGSHENG52=20210102-07:47:33.00056=Xtech10=096
    Session: FIX.4.2:HENGSHENG->Xtech
- 15:47:36 - Into onLogout
```

CAN'T find a way to parse the message sent by sentToTarget method.. Is there anything I do wrong, and in the Client object, it didn't call the onLogon method either.

Comment: You get logged out with message `MsgSeqNum too low`. Your request does not reach the counter party.

Comment: @ChristophJohn Can you tell me the reasons? is it because it has too few of fields?

Comment: No, as I said your sequence number is too low which is a critical condition and hence the connection is logged out. The simplest solution for the time being would be to reset the seqnums to 1 on both sides of the connection.